# Fix my SQL Query "ALTER USER" in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to execute a command in the mysql console.

> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY
> 'password';

But I get this error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'BY 'pass'' at line 1

Versions: 10.3.22-MariaDB-1ubuntu1 Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: [ALTER USER](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-user/) - official documentation.

Comment: Not BY but USING/AS. `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password USING PASSWORD('password');`

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update mysql.user 
 set authentication_string=password('mypass'),  
 plugin='mysql_native_password' 
where user='root';
```